# Counting characters of a UITextField crashes with NSException

Tags: swift, uitextfield, segue, action

I have a piece of code that's meant to allow the user to enter their name and advance to the next screen when the button is pressed. The program should not allow the user to move on if no value is entered. The program does detect when no name is entered and does not move to the next screen, but terminates with uncaught exception of type NSException. I'd like to allow the user to continue entering values (a name) until a name is actually entered (i.e. name value is not left empty). Is there any way I could go about doing that. While/for loops aren't seeming to work.

```
@IBAction func NameEditingDidChange(_ sender: Any) {

            NextButton.isEnabled = true

    }
    // Once button is pressed
        @IBAction func NextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // Gets user's name from textfield
    print("12345abcde")

    self.name = NameInput.text!

    // If textfield is not empty, moves to next storyboard

            if name.characters.count != 0 {

                print("in ")

                performSegue(withIdentifier: "fistBump", sender: nil)

            }
            else {
// Prints this line and terminates
                print("text field is empty")
            }
```

Comment: Needs `self.` in `self.name.characters.count` I think.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you are trying to access the `count` of `characters` array when it's nil. Change

```
if name.characters.count != 0
```

to

```
if !name.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 0):

if textfield is empty then assign empty string .

```
self.name = NameInput.text  ?? ""
```

or

```
if !NameInput.text.isEmpty {

}
```

don't put `!` to `NameInput.text!` for  force unwrapped cause if textfield empty then crash

try with this way to valid name or not

```
 func isValidName(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        // print("validate name: \(testStr)")
        let nameRegEx = "^[\p{L} \.\-]+$"

        let nameTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegEx)
        return nameTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    }
```

> ^[\p{L} .-]+$

`^` asserts position at start of the string

Match a single character present in the list below `[\p{L} \.\-]+` 
`+` Quantifier `—` Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language
  matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
`\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
`\-` matches the character - literally (case sensitive)

`$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

**Test your name from here** https://regex101.com/#javascript

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem in dealing with the optional variables.
UITextField .text property is the optional.
I hope name is you property which stores the user's input in NameInput.
Just declare your name property as optional.
var name:String?

In click action,

```
    @IBAction func NextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Gets user's name from textfield            
        self.name =         NameInput?.text?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" " , withString: "")            
        // If textfield is not empty, moves to next storyboard
        if self.name?.characters.count > 0 {// Navigate now
        }
    }
```